# Notifications rollover for a session

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, session, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a rollover on my website which will have list of notifications (small messages). These messages will be generated by the webpages as you navigate.

For example: once you hit the website, the first page can have several graphs and queries running. Some of them can return (currently showing in JavaScript alert box)
1) 2 critical jobs failed.
2) No active jobs running
As user navigate to other pages there can be more messages being generated. Note the navigation to other pages is full reload of webpage.

Since I need to keep collecting these events across multiple web pages of navigation and display them in a rollover (with a count) - what could be my options

A) I do not want to persist in db as we do not need this data for any reporting purposes. Also per user and per session data can be very large.
B) It is possibly good to just save on client side, so cookies could be an option. However I could run its length limit
C) should be using session variables? But that can make page bulky.
D) The Knock out js's observable array doeat not work with session.
Are there better alternatives? We are open to use jquery and other js tools if needed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using session to store the messages. We used CacheManager which has expiry time which cleans up the messages.

Thanks all.